# Function parameter to use interface's function signature

Tags: typescript

I have a function signature in an interface which I'd like to use as the signature for a callback parameter in some class.

```
export interface IGrid {
    gridFormat(gridCell: GridCell, grid: Grid): boolean
}
```

I'd like to do something like this:

```
validateFormat(validator: IGrid.gridFormat) {
    // ...
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this possible?

Yes as shown below:

```
export interface IGrid {
    gridFormat(gridCell: GridCell, grid: Grid): boolean
}

function validateFormat(validator: IGrid['gridFormat']) { // MAGIC 
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like the following:

```
export interface IGrid {
  gridFormat(gridCell: GridCell, grid: Grid): boolean
}

declare let igrid: IGrid;

export class Test {
  validateFormat(validator: typeof igrid.gridFormat) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Additionally, you may also declare a type for the method like below

```
declare type gridFormatMethodType = typeof igrid.gridFormat
```

to avoid the cumbersome method signature for `validateFormat`

```
validateFormat(validator: gridFormatMethodType){ ... }
```

Hope this helps.